# HearsayRequireJSBundle: Javascript files not found

Tags: symfony, requirejs, assetic

I am using [HearsayRequireJSBundle](https://github.com/hearsayit/HearsayRequireJSBundle) to implement RequireJS into my Symfony2 project.

In my Twig template I initialize as follows:

```
{{ require_js_initialize({ 'main' : 'base/main' }) }}
```

The file that then is being looked for is:

```
http://myhost.com/app_dev.php/js/base/main.js
```

This however returns a 404 not found error.

My config looks like this:

```
hearsay_require_js:
    base_directory: %kernel.root_dir%/../src/Acme/Bundle/BaseBundle/Resources/scripts
    require_js_src: bundles/acmebase/assets/scripts/require-2.1.5.min.js
    paths:
        base: '@AcmeBaseBundle/Resources/scripts'
```

Did I miss anything here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Active development on the bundle is a bit slow at the moment, but you might be better off raising an issue on github.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to define the path to your base directory twice - the `paths` configuration node is for extra paths, with `base_directory` being the default. Try changing your configuration to this:

```
hearsay_require_js:
    base_directory: %kernel.root_dir%/../src/Acme/Bundle/BaseBundle/Resources/scripts
    require_js_src: bundles/acmebase/assets/scripts/require-2.1.5.min.js
```

and alter your template to this (will now be relative to `base_directory`):

```
{{ require_js_initialize({ 'main' : 'main' }) }}
```